# Storing and retrieving custom field value of a webform in/from database?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have altered a [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) by adding a date field in different language like chinese in Drupal 7. But what steps are required to store custom field value in database and retrieving value when webform results are accessed?

I used `hook_form_alter()` to add custom date field in the existing webform, but its value doesn't get stored in database. Do I need to add some extra code to store value of custom field in db?

I am sharing my code.

```
function tekege_grievanceform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { //print_r($form_id);exit;
switch ($form_id) {
    /* for chinese */
    case 'webform_client_form_60224':
        $form['submitted']['dob'] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => t('出生日期'),
            '#weight' => 4,
            '#prefix' => '<div class="chinese_dob" id="webform_chinese_dob">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#required' => 'true'
        );

        $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_month'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => array('month' => '月'),
            '#options' => array('month' => t('月'),
                1 => t('1 月'), 2 => t('2 月'), 3 => t('3 月'), 4 => t('4 月'), 5 => t('5 月'), 6 => t('6 月'), 7 => t('7 月'), 8 => t('8 月'), 9 => t('9 月'), 10 => t('10 月'), 11 => t('11 月'), 12 => t('12 月'),
            ),
            '#description' => t('Select month.'),
            '#required' => true,
        );

        /* for 31 days */
        $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_day_31'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => array('day' => '日'),
            '#options' => array('day' => t('日'), 1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'), 4 => t('4'), 5 => t('5'), 6 => t('6'), 7 => t('7'), 8 => t('8'), 9 => t('9'), 10 => t('10'), 11 => t('11'), 12 => t('12'),
                13 => t('13'), 14 => t('14'), 15 => t('15'), 16 => t('16'), 17 => t('17'), 18 => t('18'), 19 => t('19'), 20 => t('20'), 21 => t('21'), 22 => t('22'), 23 => t('23'), 24 => t('24'),
                25 => t('25'), 26 => t('26'), 27 => t('27'), 28 => t('28'), 29 => t('29'), 30 => t('30'), 31 => t('31')),
            '#description' => t("Thirty-One Days."),
            '#required' => true,
        );

        $form['submitted']['dob']['dob_year'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => array('year' => '年'),
            '#options' => array('year' => t('年'), 1 => t('2013'), 2 => t('2012'), 3 => t('2011'), 4 => t('2010'), 5 => t('2009'), 6 => t('2008'), 7 => t('2007'), 8 => t('2006'),
                9 => t('2005'), 10 => t('2004'), 11 => t('2003'), 12 => t('2002'), 13 => t('2001'), 14 => t('2000'), 15 => t('1999'), 16 => t('1998'), 17 => t('1997'),
                18 => t('1996'), 19 => t('1995'), 20 => t('1994'), 21 => t('1993'), 22 => t('1992'), 23 => t('1991'), 24 => t('1990'), 25 => t('1989'), 26 => t('1988'),
                27 => t('1987'), 28 => t('1986'), 29 => t('1985'), 30 => t('1984'), 31 => t('1983'), 32 => t('1982'), 33 => t('1981'), 34 => t('1980'), 35 => t('1979'), 36 => t('1978'), 37 => t('1977'), 38 => t('1975'),
                39 => t('1974'), 40 => t('1973'), 41 => t('1972'), 42 => t('1971'), 43 => t('1970'), 44 => t('1969'), 45 => t('1968'), 46 => t('1967'), 47 => t('1966'),
                48 => t('1965'), 49 => t('1964'), 50 => t('1963'), 51 => t('1962'), 52 => t('1961'), 53 => t('1960'), 54 => t('1959'), 55 => t('1958'), 56 => t('1957'),
                57 => t('1956'), 58 => t('1955'), 59 => t('1954'), 60 => t('1953'), 61 => t('1952'), 60 => t('1951'), 61 => t('1950'),
            ),
            '#description' => t('Select year.'),
            '#required' => true,
        );
    }
 }
```

Comment: How did you altered webform ? using form alter ? You can add a field date to webform which can store and retrieve results like any other fields...

Comment: @AnilSagar I have added custom field in webform by form alter for some different requirements.Kindly let me know how its value can be stored and retrieved?

Comment: Please explain your requirements in your question.. Otherwise it's difficult to answer your question.. Please update your question with all details...

Comment: @AnilSagar I have updated my question.Please have a look.

Comment: Additionally you can add  webform.api functions (like `_webform_submit_component` or `hook_webform_submission_presave` or `hook_webform_submission_insert`...)

Comment: I see you are doing above just for translation .. Correct me if i am wrong.. If that's the case you can use Drupal Translation and https://drupal.org/project/webform_localization module for same..

Comment: @AnilSagar Yes I am doing it for translation. But I dont want to use any module for translation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** I was using devlopment version of webform module that was restricting my custom date fields of webform to get stored in database. It was required to be updated.
Anyways thanks for replying.